# Icon Notification in Taskbar

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing a program in C++ that at some points, will need to throw an application notification in the Taskbar. I have added an image to show what I mean.

Previously I have done some search on this, but with no luck, I've only managed to find solutions where the program creates a dialogue box and throws that to the user.

I'd just like to ask, is something like this possible with C++? I've created a small program where I would need something like this to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string input;

int main() {

while (1) {

    cout << "Type \"test\" to throw a test prompt: ";
    cin >> input;

    if (input == "test") {

        // throw prompt
    }

    else {
        cout << "That wasn't \"test\"";
        cout << '\n';
    }
}

system("pause");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Notification like what? Window with text or graphics or just flashing icon? The first type is not possible with standart functions, you should create window and place it right above your program icon the second is easy and one function call.

Comment: Hi @crea7or. In this case, just the flashing icon is all I'm looking for. More than happy to following any links to some more info that could help on this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/notification-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the [FlashWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindowex) function to flash a window's taskbar button.